# AttributeError: code does not work after a defined sorted()

Tags: python

I have created a program that takes a text file with data, consisting of four columns that contain batch, x, y, value, and produces an average value for each batch (I have two data/measurements per batch). Batch = four_vals [0] = the first column in each row. My text files can look something like this:

```
3, x-coord, y-coord, some value
3, x-coord, y-coord, some value
1, x-coord, y-coord, some value
1, x-coord, y-coord, some value
2, x-coord, y-coord, some value
2, x-coord, y-coord, some value
```

And the program will give me three average value, one for batch 3, one for batch 1 and one for batch 2.

I have also defined a sorted() function as the text files I use not always are sorted numerically according to which batch they belong to, that is, sometimes the third batch ends up at the top of the file instead of the first (as I wrote in the previous example file), but I want my output to be numeric.

The problem I have is that after I define sorted() my other code does not work, I get a `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'` in the code `for batch, sample in sorted_data.items():`  under `def average(sorted_data)`. Is this because sorted() gives me I list instead of a dict()? How can I fix this?

```
import operator

def collect_data(filename):

    data = dict() # Or data = {} #definierar denna först

    with open(filename, 'r') as h:        
        for line in h:  
        
            four_vals = line.split(',')
            batch = four_vals[0]
        
            if not batch in data:
                data[batch] = []
            try:  

                data[batch] += [(float(four_vals[1]), float(four_vals[2]), float(four_vals[3]))] # Collect data from an experiment               
            except ValueError:
                print("String not a float")
            
    sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    # print(data)
    print(sorted_data)
    return data
    return sorted_data

def average(sorted_data):    

    for batch, sample in sorted_data.items(): 
        if len(sample) > 0:
            n = 0
            x_sum = 0
        
            for (x, y, val) in sample:
                if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
                    x_sum += val
                    n += 1                    
            try:                       
                average = x_sum/n    
             
            except ZeroDivisionError: # utanför enhetscirkeln
                    print("Other measurements are made outside the unit circle")
                    continue
        
            zero_data = False
        
        else:
            zero_data = True
       
        print_average(batch, average, zero_data)
        
def print_average(batch, average, zero_data):

    if zero_data == False:
        print(batch, "\t", average)
    else:
        print(batch, "\tNo data")


def main():
'''
This is the main body of the program.
'''

    filename = input('Which data file? ')

    data = collect_data(filename)  

    sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)) 

    average(sorted_data)

# Start the main program: This is idiomatic python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please let me know if you need more information, I am new to both python and stack overflow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sorted_data` is a list of 2-tuple formed from `data.items()`, so inside `def average()` you no longer need to call `.items()` again as the list of sorted 2-tuple what's being provided already (not to mention, `list` types don't have `item` attribute, which is what the exception is warning you about).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried to replace items() with something else but never tried to just delete it. From now on I will remember that sorted() is a list of 2-tuple formed from data.items().